# How to compare dates using between clause in hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, date

I want to fetch records that fall between the two timestamp. I want this using hibernate. I tried it doing with the below query but I am not getting any output

`HQL = "From AddressInfo address where address.addressId =    '"+newValues.get("pickupAddress").toString()+"' and address.updatedDateAndTime between date_format('" + DateUtility.getTimeOfBeforeOneMinute() + "', '%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s') and date_format('"+DateUtility.getCurrentDate()+"','%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s')";`

This is the SQL Query formed from the console :

`select addressinf0_.T_ADM_NPK_ADDRESS_ID as T1_5_, addressinf0_.T_ADM_VNM_USER_ID as T2_5_, addressinf0_.T_ADM_FPK_USER_ASSIGNED_ID as T3_5_, addressinf0_.T_ADM_VNM_STREET_1 as T4_5_, addressinf0_.T_ADM_VNM_STREET_2 as T5_5_, addressinf0_.T_ADM_VNM_STREET_3 as T6_5_, addressinf0_.T_ADM_VNM_CITY as T7_5_, addressinf0_.T_ADM_VNM_STATE as T8_5_, addressinf0_.T_ADM_VNM_ZIPCODE as T9_5_, addressinf0_.T_ADM_DNM_LATITUDE as T10_5_, addressinf0_.T_ADM_DNM_LONGITUDE as T11_5_, addressinf0_.T_ADM_TNM_CREATE_DATETIME as T12_5_, addressinf0_.T_ADM_TNM_UPDATE_DATETIME as T13_5_ from t_address_master addressinf0_ where addressinf0_.T_ADM_NPK_ADDRESS_ID='19' and (addressinf0_.T_ADM_TNM_UPDATE_DATETIME between date_format('Tue Oct 02 17:09:53 EDT 2012', '%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s') and date_format('Tue Oct 02 17:10:53 EDT 2012', '%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s'))`

My DB has a record with T_ADM_TNM_UPDATE_DATETIME  = 10/2/2012 5:10:40 PM

But the resultset is not able to fetch this query...I don't know wwhere I am going wrong.

Can anyone please guide me further

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  Can you paste the exception you are getting?

Comment: Nope I am not getting any exception but I am not able to get the desired output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using HQL parameters instead of concatenate.

Take this example:

```
Map<String, Object> parameterNameAndValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();

Date startDate;
Date endDate;

// Assign values to startDate and endDate

parameterNameAndValues.put("startDate", startDate);
parameterNameAndValues.put("endDate", endDate);

String hqlQuery = "FROM EntityName WHERE fechaInicio BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate";

Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hqlQuery);

for (Entry<String, Object> e : parameterNameAndValues.entrySet()) {
    query.setParameter(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
}

return query.list();
```

This will bind the date parameters and hibernate will make the necessary convertions for you avoiding sanity checks and errors. Remember that even if MySQL saves Date objects in that format other databases may not and it will undermine Hibernate help.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

java.util.Date date = df.parse(startDate);

java.util.Date date1 = df.parse(endDate);

Date fromDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()); 

Date toDate = new java.sql.Date(date1.getTime());

return this.sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery("From UserDailyLogin where userProfile.userId='"+id+"' And createdDate BETWEEN '"+startDate+ "' AND '"+endDate+"' ").list();
```