# Hibernate criteria returning list which contain same objects, How to resolve it?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have written restriction as follows,

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
 Date frmDate= df.parse("2014-01-01");
 Date toDate=df.parse("2014-09-16");

 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(HistoryLatitudeBean.class);
          criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("vehicleno",12));
          criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("rdate", frmDate)); 
          criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("rdate", toDate));
          criteria.add(Restrictions.between("rdate", frmDate, toDate));

          List<HistoryLatitudeBean> groupList=criteria.list();// <---groupList contains same objects

          for(HistoryLatitudeBean hb : groupList){

              System.out.println(hb.getLat());
          }
```

My bean is like this,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="hlatlng")
public class HistoryLatitudeBean {

@Id
@Column(name="vehicleno")
private int vehicleno;
@Column(name="lat")
private String lat;
@Column(name="lng")
private String lng;
@Column(name="status")
private String status;
@Column(name="rdate")
private Date rdate;
@Column(name="rtime")
private Date rtime;

//getters and setters
}
```

I am trying for following query, 
`select * from hlatlng where vehicleno=12 and rdate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2014-06-05'`

In DB it gives 11 rows which has diff values.
When I execute it through hibernate criteria, it gives 11 objects of same value. I checked through debug in eclipse all objets in `groupList` same `id`, how can I resolve it. Please help me.

Comment: why are you using gt, lt and between. For clear query you can use hql and pass the variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699064/how-to-compare-dates-using-between-clause-in-hibernate

Comment: I tried like that , that is also giving same output.

Comment: look at my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738350/how-to-write-a-hql-query-for-between-clause-for-date-range/25739659#25739659

Comment: Your `vehicleno` is an `id`. How do you expect to get more than one result from your query querying by id?

Comment: oh yes..,actually in that table there is no primary key. if I remove `@Id` will it leads to any problem?

Comment: @AleksandrM If I remove `@Id` annotation it gives me error as `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.abc.its.beans.HistoryLatitudeBean` How to resolve this

Comment: you can't create any object in hibernate without Id, it will throw Identifier not found for particular class.

Comment: @Swaraj can I make it foreign key without primary key.?

Comment: No bro, you can't only solution of your problem is making surrogate key as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767277/hibernate-and-no-pk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be resolved with `Aleksandr M` comment.

You are missing a field annotated with `@Id`. Each `@Entity` needs an `@Id` - this is the primary key in the database.

`Hibernate` requires an identifier for each entity.

also, need to modify you query for omitting `vehicleno` since it is the primary key and will return the same result everytime.

```
@Id
@Column(name="vehicleno")
private int vehicleno;
```

Comment: yes I have these three lines in my bean, but in my table I dont have a primary key, so I tried without `@Id`. but it throws error.

Comment: @Raghu see my answer, clearly explained there, either make new field as `Id` or if you are using existing `vehicleno` as `Id`, the you will get one record only.

Comment: Yes .. , Thanks bro , I have created one more field for id . then it worked.

Comment: Thank you @ankur-singhal. Your answer helped me too!